# Way around dragmove changing mouse state to released

Tags: wpf, preview

I am trying to make a window movable if a user clicks anywhere within the window and then drags while the mouse is pressed. Contrarily, if a user presses and release the mouse, keeping it's position constant, I want whatever is inside the window to get clicked. Basically, it is a toolbar that is draggable from anywhere within or on it.

The problem is that DragMove() changes the mouse state to released and I need whatever is inside the window to receive a press and release when the window is not being dragged.

```
private void currentWindow_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        double tempX = currentWindow.Left;
        double tempY = currentWindow.Top;
        this.DragMove();
        if (currentWindow.Left == tempX && currentWindow.Top == tempY)
        {
            // at this point e.ButtonState is Released but I need it to be Pressed!
            // some code here to press the button
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `e.Handled = false;` right after `this.DragMove();`?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I have in there now, but it does nothing because e.Handled's default is false and this.DragMove() never touches it (that I'm aware of). But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Since calling DragMove suspends mouse notifications until the mouse left button up event, have you tried calling DragMove in the PreviewMouseMove (assuming it's moved some X number of pixels since the left button down)?

Comment: Yeeee that's a good suggestion, it worked thanks.